# Display contents of XML (property mapping) in a JSP page

Tags: java, xml, jsp, spring-mvc, mapping

I have a Property Mapping (colorMap.xml):

```
<bean id="B_colorMapping" class="com.project.color.colorMap">
    <property name="map">
        <map>
            <entry key="1" value="blue" />
            <entry key="2" value="blue-green" />

            <entry key-ref="10" value-ref="B_colorMapping" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="R_colorMapping" class="com.project.color.colorMap">
    <property name="map">
        <map>
            <entry key="1" value="red" />
            <entry key="2" value="red-yellow" />

            <entry key-ref="10" value-ref="R_colorMapping" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And the `com.project.color.colorMap` codes look like this:

```
public class colorMap {
    private Map<Object, Object> map;
    public Map<Object, Object> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
    public void setMap(Map<Object, Object> Cmap) {
        map = Cmap;
    }
}
```

Right now, what is happening, I manually update the colorMap.xml by adding entries and values. What I'm planning to do is to create a JSP page to handle the adding of the values in my xml.

for now, I want to display the values of my xml on the JSP page.

For example: (on the JSP page...)

```
B_colorMapping:
Color Key: 1         Value: blue
Color Key: 2         Value: blue-green

R_colorMapping:
Color Key:1          Value: red
Color Key:2          Value: red-yellow
```

Can someone offer a help or tip on how to do this? THis is spring MVC (Object, Map, ModelAndView).

I'm stuck on this one.

Comment: What is your actual problem ? Is there any problem in retriving map values in java side ? Or is there any problem in passing that map to JSP page?

Comment: @Prasath Hello. I am seeking help on how can I do my desired output. I want the front end to handle all. I dont want to update the xml file manually anymore.

Comment: Do you want to show those values in jsp ? Is that you want ?

Comment: Or from UI you need to update the XML ?

Comment: @Prasath Yes indeed. I want to show the values of my XML to a JSP page. And also, I want to update the XML by the UI.

Comment: One big question,even after you update config xml via jsp,you still need to redeploy the application in order for the config file to be read by application.How do you plan to achieve that?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal I'm not seeing that yet. I am not sure if I'm getting your thought right. But as what Iam planning to do is to display the contents of my XML on a JSP and be able to update it via JSP. It will be glad if I you can help me here?